# MessageBox.Show right to left reading not working

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

Hey I'll make it simple. I want to make a MessageBox of this string "abc" and it will be read from right to left.

I tried this  `Messagebox.Show("abc",MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading);`

what's worng with this ?

this is the error i get :

> 1:"cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxOptions' to 'string"
>
> > 2:"cannot convert from 'string' to
> >     'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons'"
> >
> > > 3:"The best overloaded  method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(string,
> > >        string)' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: Your supposed to tell us that bit, whats "not working"? Also, I thought right to left, did it by word not letter?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? And that code wouldn't compile anyeays

Comment: ok ok im sorry i will give you the error , i cant run the program and this ( i edited my post)

Comment: I dont think this is the answer you really wanted but its the answer that will help you the most in the long run - Take a look at [`this`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba3x8zfh.aspx)

Comment: @Sayse , this is helpful but if i dont want to use all the caption and the buttons and all this , i just want to write a message from right to left .. without define all the other things

Comment: I think you need to read up a bit more on constructors

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If it's not displaying left to right, try this:

```
//note the capitalized B in Box
MessageBox.Show(new string("abc".Reverse()), "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcons.None, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign);
```

If you want something like this:

```
----------------------------X--
-------------------------------
|                             |
|                             |
|                        cba  |
|                             |
|                        |OK| |
-------------------------------
```

I think it doesn't have to do with that though, it's mainly you got the parameters wrong. wrong. Here, fixed:

```
//note the capitalized B in Box
MessageBox.Show("abc", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcons.None, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading);
```

There's also an ugly way to do this, but it means you don't have to add the extraparams. First, make a class called MessageBoxEx, and the contents of it are...

```
static class MessageBoxEx
{
    public static void Show(string content, MessageBoxOptions options)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(content, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcons.None,          MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, options);
    }
}
```

and call it like `MessageBoxEx.Show("abc", MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading);`.

Comment: I must write it execly like you ? (i mean if i dont want to write the MessageBoxButtons.OK and MessageBoxIcons.None and all the rest ,exeptMessageBoxOptions.RtlReading

Comment: Well, there's another way to do it... but it's ugly. I'll add it.

Comment: Thanks ! but I think I will use the first the (the secoend is ugly as you said..)

Answer (score 5):

Write a method that will default all the values you don't want to set.

```
//Message is the string message and options is where you specify RTL
public void ShowMessageBox(string message, MessageBoxOptions options)
{
    MessageBox.Show(message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcons.None, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, options);
}
```

Then all you have to do is call

```
ShowMessageBox("abc", MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading)
```

Comment: +1 for giving the OP a way to call his or her `MessageBox` exactly the way he wanted to =)  Also for living in CO ;)

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance it IS ugly, but still direct.  Not condoning the method whatsoever.  The OP should be using the normal overloads for the `MessageBox` class, your answer was correct as well.

Answer (score 5):

I have been in situation like this, and the best way I found is to combine the two flags: `RtlReading` and `RightAlign`:

```
MessageBox.Show("Msg body", "Msg title", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning, 
         MessageBoxResult.OK, MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading | MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you are using has a signature that matches 
`MessageBox.Show(string, string)` Which tries to display a string and a caption for the title. Instead, what you want is something that has all the arguments filled in:

```
MessageBox.Show("abc def","",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading);
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix the `MessageBoxOptions` like below :

```
MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign | MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading
```

in your case :

```
MessageBox.Show("abc", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcons.None,
MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign | MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading);
```

hope it helps.