# Dialog box in arabic style

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I am working on Arabic collision. I have achieved almost everything some Dialog boxes(Print Dialog Box) in my application are still not localizing to Arabic.

```
frmPrintPreview.show()
```

I am using like this while opening a Print-dialog

In my project some Dialog box are present such as Font Dialog,Print Dialog etc...

Is it possible to change dialog box in Arabic style(Right to left pattern)?and also message Box in Arabic pattern...?

```
Private Sub PrintBarcodeStartToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object,ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PrintBarcodeStartToolStripMenuItem.Click

    scanprogressTS.Value = 0

    BLBPrintText = "START"

    BLBPrint = True

    scanprogressTS.Value = scanprogressTS.Maximum

    changelayoutform(frmPrintPreview)

    frmPrintPreview.Show()

    scanprogressTS.Value = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: http://www.developerfusion.com/article/1912/multilingual-support-in-c/3/ refer to the link buddy hope it helps  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993540/messagebox-show-right-to-left-reading-not-working

Comment: why `c#` tag. code is `vb` !!

Comment: Both are same almost....sry for mistake

Comment: Hi Amarnath almost my Problem solved about messageBox butthe button which is displayed in messagebox i.e OK button still comming in English while Arabic Login also...but msg ,icon are working perfectly...also what about PrintDialog Box

Answer (score 0):

**Labels**

Yes, You can set the WinForm labels to display from right to left. Label control has property called `RightToLeft`(False by default) set this to true.

[image: Label Property]

---

**MessageBox**

Yes, You can also display message box in Arabic style, One of the parameter in MessageBox.Show() method is called [MessageBoxOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). its an enumeration, You have to set `MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading` which will display message box in Arabic style.

Ex:

```
MessageBox.Show("Right to left Text", "Test", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading);
```

Comment: MessageBoxButtons.OK...............while displaying MessageBox All are displaying in Arabic Style only but except OK button ...what to do for that........

Comment: @Saurabh What do you mean OK button is not displayed in Arabic style ? how you want to display it ?

Comment: OK button Displaying with english letter only after Arabic login also.....above ex u have given thats working in arabic style only except ok button text displaying in english letter

Comment: I am not getting properly plz help me